# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `Name` on serializer `AppointmentSerializer`

Tags: python, django

When attempting to get a value for field `Name` on serializer `AppointmentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Response` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Response' object has no attribute 'Name'.

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    DoctorName = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.DoctorName

class Appointment(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    Phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    Email = models.EmailField()
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)
    Comments = models.TextField(max_length=60)
    Doctor= models.ForeignKey(Doctor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

**serializer.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Appointment
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ['Name','Phone','Email','Date','Comments','Doctor']
```

**views.py**

```
class AppointmentDetailView(APIView):

    def get_object(self,id):
        try:
            return Appointment.objects.get(id=id)

        except Appointment.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        appointment = self.get_object(id)
        serializer = AppointmentSerializer(appointment)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    def put(self, request, id=None):
        appointment = self.get_object(id)
        serializer = AppointmentSerializer(appointment, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, id=None):
        appointment = self.get_object(id)
        appointment.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('detail/<int:id>/', AppointmentDetailView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Did you migrate your database?

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Appointment
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # You need to add your fields exclusively like that:

    Name = serializers.CharField() # maybe_some_attributes ex: required, allow_null etc.
    Phone = serializers.CharField()
    .
    .

class Meta:
    model = Appointment
    fields = ['Name','Phone','Email','Date','Comments','Doctor']
```